# Is There a function to get a *.exe file's Product Name?

Tags: c++, qt, file, winapi, exe

## How can i get the product name with exe file's string path?

i tried to get a product name with 'VerQueryValue' function in MSDN.

what i get this function is only version

i want to have a product name

---

And, Qt is not support to get a file information (file Version, file Product Name etc.)

Comment: what i want to get a product Name's program is not mine!

Comment: I see. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be retrieved using `GetFileVersionInfoExW` followed by `VerQueryValueW` with appropriate query string like `\StringFileInfo\<4_digit_hex_lang_id><4_digit_hex_code_page_id>\ProductName`. In this example I'm trying to get info from neutral / fallback resource using hardcoded IDs, but available IDs for different localizations can be retrieved by querying `\VarFileInfo\Translation`.

```
#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

#define SZ_STRING_FILE_INFO_W L"StringFileInfo"
#define SZ_PRODUCT_NAME_W L"ProductName"
#define SZ_HEX_LANG_ID_EN_US_W L"0409"
#define SZ_HEX_CODE_PAGE_ID_UNICODE_W L"04B0"

int wmain()
{
    auto const psz_file_path{L"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe"};
    [[maybe_unused]] DWORD dummy{};
    auto const required_buffer_size
    {
        ::GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW
        (
            FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL, psz_file_path, ::std::addressof(dummy)
        )
    };
    if(0 == required_buffer_size)
    {
        return ::GetLastError();
    }
    auto const p_buffer
    {
        ::std::make_unique<char[]>
        (
            static_cast<::std::size_t>(required_buffer_size)
        )
    };
    auto const get_version_info_result
    {
        ::GetFileVersionInfoExW
        (
            FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL
        ,   psz_file_path
        ,   DWORD{}
        ,   required_buffer_size
        ,   static_cast<void *>(p_buffer.get())
        )
    };
    if(FALSE == get_version_info_result)
    {
        return ::GetLastError();
    }
    LPVOID p_value{};
    UINT value_length{};
    auto const query_result
    {
        ::VerQueryValueW
        (
            static_cast<void *>(p_buffer.get())
        ,   L"\\" SZ_STRING_FILE_INFO_W
            L"\\" SZ_HEX_LANG_ID_EN_US_W SZ_HEX_CODE_PAGE_ID_UNICODE_W
            L"\\" SZ_PRODUCT_NAME_W
        ,   ::std::addressof(p_value)
        ,   ::std::addressof(value_length)
        )
    };
    if
    (
        (FALSE == query_result)
        or
        (nullptr == p_value)
        or
        ((required_buffer_size / sizeof(wchar_t)) < value_length)
    )
    {
        return ::GetLastError();
    }
    ::std::wstring const product_name
    {
        static_cast<wchar_t const *>(p_value)
    ,   static_cast<::std::size_t>(value_length)
    };
    // product_name should contain "Microsoft® Windows® Operating System"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but that variable initialization thing you are doing is difficult to read.  I'm sure it's a new style that's being evangelized in modern C++, but it would aid to the readability if you just used normal assignment operators.Especially since all these variables being initialized are plain old value types or simple pointers.  For example:  `auto required_buffer_size = ::GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW(...);`

Comment: @selbie I just prefer to use `=` only when I'm really performing an assignment. Note that this also implies using substitutions for use of `=` in other contexts, such as `using type = ...`,  `virtual void method() = 0;`, `void foo() = delete;`.

Comment: @sel: I know how you feel. It takes time to get used to the uniform initialization syntax, but once you do, you'll find yourself wondering, why you haven't used it before. It is closer to the intent and implementation than 'assignment-lookalike-initialization'. If only `initializer_list`s weren't as broken, we would finally have a single, uniform replacement for the 19+ ways to initialize an object.

Comment: There's several other things about this style that are also uncomfortable beside the initialization style. There are several unnecessary `static_cast` calls.   Also, `std::addressof` instead of `&`.